# Search specific string in last line of text & execute program when criteria met via Windows Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, find-replace

My objective is to create a batch file that search for specific string "--- Exit ---" in the last line of data in a filename "output.log" & execute program when string exists on the last sentence.

The "output.log" is a log files always update itself >3 sec interval since it is a log file dump (hence the last sentence always will be different)

```
...
08-15-19 14:58:03 [10220] INFO root <> - Information: General - "Stopping all customize processes" () 
08-15-19 14:58:03 [10220] INFO root <> - Information: General - "All customize processes stopped" () 
08-15-19 14:58:03 [10220] INFO root <> - ----- Exit  -----
```

N.B. there are dozens of "--- Exit ---" in the complete document.

If the "--- Exit ---" appears on the last sentence of the "output.log", the batch file shall execute a program (e.g. calc.exe)

With extremely limited knowledge in batch file, my initial plan is to:

```
1) cd into the correct directory

2) Copy file from source folder (output.log) into another folder 

3) Using FindRepl.bat, replace "--- Exit ---" to "--- Ex1t ---" and store it into another name (output2.log) (I was not able to save the replaced text into the original "output.log", hence i do this)

3) delete "output.log" 

4) rename "output2.log" to "output.log" 

5) execute program (when --- Exit ---- exist; but not --- Ex1t ---)... 

6) loop from the top
```

The issue I encountered is I am not able delete "output.log" & rename "output.log". 
**Also there is a critical flaw as the original output.log dump still contains "Exit" inside, hence.. create infinite loop**

Is there any script/alternative the batch could read last sentence of the output.log & once the last sentence contains "--- Exit ---", then execute specific program (e.g. calc.exe)?

It would be great if there is an explanation of how each line work, it would be great for a ppl with zero batch experience like me!

Comment: get the last line of the file with `for "delims=" %%a in (output.log) do set "lastline=%%a"`. The rest should be trivial. (please adapt your question, if you still have issues)

Comment: @Stephan Thanks for your feedback, but i wonder in which position should i place? It would be great if you can clarify the code to determine the string "--- Exit ---" with the delimiter in action.

Comment: `if not "%lastline:--- Exit ---=%" == "%lastline%" echo last linecontains ---- Exit ----`

Comment: @stephan So i cd into the right directory, followed by your code for "delims..... & if not %lastline...., the cmd would just prompt all the lines available in the output.log. Doesn't seems as it's intended I guess. ```setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
cd C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test folder
for /f "UseBackQ delims==" %%a in (output.log) do set "lastline=%%a"
if  "%lastline:--- Exit ---%" == "%lastline%" echo last linecontains ---- Exit ----```

Comment: you forgot the `not`.